# Average of arrival times excluding outliers

Tags: algorithms, mean

I'm working with a dataset of arrival times as below:

```
stop 1        stop 2       stop 3
09:01:00      09:03:01     09:05:12
09:01:23      09:03:03     09:05:13
09:01:12      09:02:55     09:05:40
09:02:01      09:03:30     09:04:44
09:00:45      09:03:31     09:05:55
...
```

The data correspond to arrival times for bus stops. I would like to calculate the average arrival time for each stop. I could calculate the median but I want to exclude the outliers.

For example if one day the bus arrives to Stop1 at 09:03:55 (due to traffic jam, weather conditions, etc), this arrival time will not reflect the normal behavior and I want to exclude it from my calculations (for stop1). So my question is how I could determine the range of "valid" arrival times (for example from 09:00:00 to 09:02:30) just with my dataset?

**EDIT**

I've mentioned 'the median', but if you know a better approach to this problem I would like to know it.

Comment: "*I could calculate the median but I want to exclude the outliers.*" --- well, the median ignores the outliers (except that it notices which side of the data they're on). If you actually want to *calculate* the average (i.e. the mean) arrival time (which as worded is a sample quantity), you *can't* ignore the outliers. If you define it as the only the average of under normal behavior, how can we discern whether a large value is from 'normal' behavior or from abnormal behavior, unless you supply that information as well?

Comment: _how can we discern whether a large value is from 'normal' behavior or from abnormal behavior, unless you supply that information as wel?_ That is what I wonder :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I will give you a comparison between median and average. We say that the median is more "robust" to outliers than the mean. To get an idea of what robust means, consider the following data: 1, 1, 1, 2, 100. The median of this data is 1 with the obvious outlier 100 having the same effect on the median if it was 2 instead. The mean, however, is 21.2 and the value of 100 in the data had a large effect on calculating the mean.

Now, in your case I would calculate confidence intervals. A 95% Confidence intervals has the following interpretation: if one calculates confidence intervals for independent samples which are taken repeatedly from the same population then 95% of the intervals will include the unknown true mean arrival time.

If you're unsure about how to calculate confidence intervals, in this case you would likely use a confidence interval for a Student's t distribution which you can read about here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution#Confidence_intervals